# Why can you only use an ID once in HTML (aside from the obvious)

Tags: html

Why can you only use an ID once on an HTML page or app? Is it's unique quality something that was written into the spec during the creation of HTML?

I'm having trouble even figuring out the right thing to google to get to the bottom of this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's in the spec.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2 and yes is to refer something otherwise it will be very difficult to search something on the document

Comment: Google "w3c html5". Hit the first result. Search for "id attribute" inside that page. [Done](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

Comment: Relevant article - [The Difference between ID and Class](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/). He used Barcodes and Serial Numbers to clarify the idea of using IDs.

Comment: ids are like social security numbers while classes are like first, middle, and last names. both are important, but they have different purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations and references!

Answer (score 2):

Yes its in the official specification.  You can have more than one element with the same id but it will invalidate your HTML and can cause other problems.   You should only use an id once because its means to give you a unique reference to a element in the DOM which is very handy.

For example take social security numbers.  They are designed to be unique to each person.  You could give two people the same number but if would cause problems.  Think of it like that

Comment: I thought my comment above would be an id, but it was a class.